# Как организовать поиск устройств Bluethooth (сопряженных и новых устройств)

Tags: android, bluetooth

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQ_CODE_BT = 1001;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


//     Обработчик OnClick
        View.OnClickListener OnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch (view.getId()) {
                 case R.id.bluetooth_button:
                        if (bluethoothButton.isChecked())
                            enableBluetooth();
                        else
                            disableBluetooth();
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        bluethoothButton.setOnClickListener(OnClick);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        stateBluethooth();
    }

    //          Если блютуз не поддерживаеться
    private void noSupportedBluetooth() {
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.noSupportedBluethooth, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    //           Включаем блютуз
    private void enableBluetooth() {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_BT);
        }
    }

    //          Проверяем состояние блютуз
    private void stateBluethooth(){
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            bluethoothButton.setChecked(true);
        }
       }


    //          Выключаем блютуз
    private void disableBluetooth() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
        }
    }




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поиск устройств можно сделать таким способом:

```
mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery(); 
mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();

    //Finding devices                 
    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) 
    {
        // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
       mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
    }
  }
};

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND); 
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Получение списка сопряженных устройств происходит так:

```
public class PairedDeviceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private ListView listView;
  private ArrayList<String> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<>();

private void getBluetoothPairedDevices(final ArrayList<String> deviceList, final ListView listView){
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This device not support bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableAdapter = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableAdapter, 0);
        }
        Set<BluetoothDevice> all_devices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (all_devices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice currentDevice : all_devices) {
                deviceList.add("Device Name: "+currentDevice.getName() + "\nDevice Address: " + currentDevice.getAddress());
                listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplication(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, deviceList));
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_paired_device);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    getBluetoothPairedDevices(mDeviceList,listView);
 }
}
```

Comment: А как сделать сопряжение с новым устройством по клику на него?